# Force users to recache url

Tags: html, redirect

I had a setting in my domain controller to redirect my domain to another domain.

### Example

Redirect `http://mysite.com` to `http://othersite.com`

I removed the redirect about one week ago, but some users are still seeing the redirect to http://othersite.com.

I found that clearing the browser cache fixes the problem.

Is there any way I can force users to update their cache when they go to my site?

Comment: What did you use for the redirection ? PHP , htaccess ??

Comment: in the html header add an include to an unexisting file

Answer (score 1):

. You need to look into the [HTTP protocol](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc2616.pdf). There is quite a large section about the caching model. See section 13. There are a variety of things that you can do depending on your desires.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding some headers to force browser to fetch... along the lines of:

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()) {
        @session_start();   
    }
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['form_submitted'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['form_submitted']);
        header('Location: ?' . uniqid());
        #header('Refresh: 0');
    }
?>
```